# Any e-learning apps similar to projecteuler.net?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've been using projecteuler.net to learn a bit of programming, and I think this is a great format to learn other stuff (learning by doing). I'm wondering if there's any other sites similar to this, that in essence is a list of challenges to learn a discipline.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/), [Top Coder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc) & [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.pl/)

Comment: These are great, but do you happen to know any that don't involve programming? I.E. Home improvement, Gardening, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, as problem based learning is suited to programming challenges as it is very easy to submit your solution online - other subjects such as gardening would be quite hard to submit online! :)

However, you could check out this site http://www.mrsoshouse.com/pbl/pblin.html

It has various resources on Problem Based Learning along with various Activities, Problems and Projects on a range of subject.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion: using http://www.wikihow.com can teach you various things in "learning by doing"  methodology.